# What is the best HTTP status code for blocked user profile in rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http

I wrote an API for social app in Rails. This app likes Facebook, users can block other users. If user A block user B, user B can't view profile page of user A. So what is the best HTTP code status I should return: 404, 403, 204 or 200(render nothing) ?

Comment: `page not found: 404` is most appropriate

Comment: This is a good reference when you don't know how to pick the best status code http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/, btw in your case 403 IMO is the best choice!

Comment: Thanks for your support @@

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I much prefer to use `403 Forbidden`

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood  the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.
>
> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of 404 (Not Found).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3

Answer (score 5):

A best practice for this is `403`, however doing so will expose the fact that user has been blocked. If you don't want that, you can return `404`. Github, as an example, for unauthorized access to private repos always returns `404`.

Comment: For the standard login on your website, though, 403 should be just fine since you certainly know the page as it is public anyway. Also 403 is important for a REST API.

Comment: Using 403 also exposes that the resource existst at that URL. If you don't want unapproved users to know that `http://example/mysecretfile.txt` exists, you should return 404 instead.