# Alternative to http status code 403 for a banned user

Tags: http

I am wondering what the best practice for the following scenario is: I have an application where an agent authenticates on behalf of a customer.

If the customer is banned, what is the best practice for the http status code I return them?

When I return a 403 it seems as if the request they made was invalid, it does not convey to the agent the user is banned. In the same sense I do not want to send a 401 unless the credentials used to make the request were invalid.

I have read a few answers and the spec and haven't found what I was looking for. I was leaning towards a custom 2XX response i.e (230) or something like 406 or 451.

Looking forward to your input.

Resources used:

- https://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/
- https://httpstatuses.com/
- [What is the best HTTP status code for blocked user profile in rails api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332740/what-is-the-best-http-status-code-for-blocked-user-profile-in-rails-api)

Comment: Yes, 403 would be the right code to use, it states a FORBIDDEN ressource (banned, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, you should stay with the standard: `403`.

From: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

> 10.4.4 403 Forbidden The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request
> SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the
> server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled,
> it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the
> server does not wish to make this information available to the client,
> the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

Returning `FORBIDDEN` is very straight forward as the the other codes may be perceived as ambiguous.